# Is there a way to avoid insertions in a mysql table filtering the user and the date

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tablet, insertion

I have a mysql table (bill) that contains a date field,

**id|cod_bill|mount|dale_date**
1|0001|12.00|2015-01-20 10:05:05
2|0002|10.50|2015-01-25 13:12_33

This table belongs to a database (my_shop) owned by the user (sales_agent). This user can connect remotely to the mysql server, using a local client app. What I want is, from the server and without touching the client app, to prevent insertions with date before '2015-01-01 00:00:00'. I am using phpmyadmin and have the root permissions.

Answer (score 1):

if you're letting them insert directly to mysql from phpmyadmin or a local mysql client then you can't.

a small hack to get what you want is adding a trigger on insert / update that deletes the row if the date is wrong